# Is it possible to create an ordering for a list of generic elements?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Is it possible to create a function that takes a list of elements of any imaginable type and returns an operator that can act as a comparator for ordering the elements? In other words,

```
template typename<T> ??? getComparator ( T a )
{
     // ...
}
```

where I put `???` because I'm not sure what the return type would be. The idea, however, is that if I called

```
getComparator(int i)
```

it would probably return

```
bool smallerThan(int a, int b) { return (a < b); }
```

and if I created a custom object

```
struct thingamabob { int i; std::string s; int ***** ptr; }
thingamabob myThing;
```

I could feed `myThing` into `getComparator` and it would figure out how to create a function of return type `bool` that takes two objects of type `myThing` and is that such for any 3 objects

```
thingamabob thing1, thing2, thing3;
```

with

```
thing1 != thing2 && thing2 != thing3 && thing1 != thing3
```

then I can get some `<` such that either

```
thing1 <= thing2 && thing2 <= thing3
```

or

```
thing1 <= thing3 && thing3 <= thing2
```

or

```
thing3 <= thing1 && thing1 <= thing2
```

or

```
thing2 <= thing1 && thing1 <= thing3
```

or

```
thing2 <= thing3 && thing3 <= thing1
```

or

```
thing3 <= thing1 && thing1 <= thing2
```

or

```
thing3 <= thing2 && thing2 <= thing3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature in C++ (as of 2015, hence including all standards up to C++14). However, Bjarne Stroustrup has written a proposal to add [default comparison operators](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4175.pdf) to the standard.

What this essentially does is generating a comparison operator for you, in case you don't declare these operators yourself. It is simply the lexicographical ordering on the data members of your class / struct. However, this is not implemented in any mainstream compiler as of right now, nor is it certain that it ever will be added to an official C++ standard. You'll have to stick with implementing it on your own.

The proposal defines some circumstances in which no default comparison operator will be generated, e.g. if there is a pointer member. This is because such a comparison may easily invoke undefined behavior.

The straightforward code that does exactly that is:

```
bool operator<(const Type& first, const Type& second)
{
    return std::tie(first.member1,  first.member2) <
           std::tie(second.member1, second.member2);
}

bool operator>=(const Type& first, const Type& second)
{
   return !(first < second);
}

bool operator>(const Type& first, const Type& second)
{
   return second < first;
}

bool operator<=(const Type& first, const Type& second)
{
   return !(first > second);
}
```

Comment: The cited proposal does not generate comparison operators for arbitrary types. For example, types with pointer members are excluded.

Comment: @rici Yes, and that's actually very good: It's UB to compare pointers that belong to different blocks of memory.

Comment: Sure, I understand the rationale. It was just a clarification since the OP is about arbitrary objects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you're looking for [`std::less<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less): that's a function object that will compare two objects of type `T`.

However, it will need `operator<` defined - which will work fine for `int`, but for `thingamabob` - you will have to write that operator yourself. How's the compiler to know what you mean by saying one `thingamabob` is less than another unless you tell it?